# Access the MouseDoubleClick Events of a textbox in a UserControl

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I have an form that have a `UserControl`. The user control has a `textbox`. I want to access the `MouseDoubleClick` events of the `textbox` since when I tried using the MouseDoubleClick event of the `UserControl` nothing happens when I double clicks it. I have a copy of the source code of the `UserControl`. Please see below code that i am trying.

```
  private void UserControl_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Mouse Double Click!");
    }
```

Comment: textBox1.MouseDoubleClick += (s, e) => OnMouseDoubleClick(e);

Answer (score 0):

I already resolve it: I added an event in the user control.

`public event MouseEventHandler txtMouseDoubleClick;`

```
private void TextBox_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.txtMouseDoubleClick!= null)
            this.txtMouseDoubleClick(this, e);
    }
```